# Proving limits of sequences using squeeze theorem/ simple limit theorems

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$1. \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2+4n}{n^2-5} = \frac{n^2(1+\frac{4}{n})}{n^2(1-\frac{5}{n^2})} = \frac{1+\frac{4}{n}}{1-\frac{5}{n^2}} = \frac{\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}1+\frac{4}{n}}{\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}1 - \frac{5}{n^2}} = \frac{1 + (\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{4}{n} = 4\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 4(0) = 0) }{1 - (\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{5}{n^2} = 5 \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = 5(0) = 0}$$ Therefore the answer is 1

$$2. \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\cos n}{n} = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \cos n \cdot \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}  $$ Can I just then assume that the answer is zero because $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to zero?

$$3. \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt{4-\frac{1}{n}}-2)n= \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt{4-\frac{1}{n}}-2) \cdot \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}n \le \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \cdot\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}n = \infty$$

$$4. \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+7}= ((-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+7})^2 = (-1)^{2n}\frac{n}{(n+7)^2}\le (-1)^{2n}\frac{1}{n^2} = 0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2. You should say that since cos  is bounded and as $\frac{1}{n}$ tends to zero, your limit is zero. Since  this result does not hold case $ \frac{f(n)}{n}$ and $f(n)$ is not bounded  as $n $  tends to  $\infty$.

For 3. How did you know that  $ \sqrt{ 4-\frac{1}{n}} -2 \leq \sqrt {\frac{1}{n}} $ . (it is not true for  $n=2$). Thus you may do the following  $$n \Bigg(\sqrt{ 4-\frac{1}{n}} -2  \Bigg)= n \Bigg(\sqrt{ 4-\frac{1}{n}} -2 \times \frac{\sqrt{ 4-\frac{1}{n}} +2}{\sqrt{ 4-\frac{1}{n}} +2}   \Bigg) = n \Bigg(\frac{ 4-\frac{1}{n} -4}{\sqrt{ 4-\frac{1}{n}} +2}   \Bigg)= n \Bigg(\frac{-\frac{1}{n} }{\sqrt{ 4-\frac{1}{n}} +2}   \Bigg) = \frac{-1 }{\sqrt{ 4-\frac{1}{n}} +2}     $$
and this last term tends to  $\frac{-1}{4}$ as  $n $ tends to  $ \infty$.

For 4. How did you write  $ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(-1)^n \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+7}= ((-1)^n\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+7})^2$ you think it is logically true  !!?? 
This  limit can be analysis in the following context :  as $ n \rightarrow  \infty $ we have  $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+7} \approx  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, and as  $ (-1)^n$ is bounded between $-1$  and  $1$ then your limit is zero.